# Dynamically create and dispose of dataframes

Tags: pyspark

I have been struggling with this one for some time. I wanted to create a data check notebook, that runs through rows of metadata and check if specific value from specific column if good. Things like data types, length, nulls etc are checked. Final part I need to see if row of that value has proper join with dependent table based on some keys. My problem is, I want to have this dynamically, so for all other parts I used UDFs. But within UDF I am not able to dynamically create a dataframes and now I am stuck.

This is my improper UDF:

```
@udf
def join_check (main_table,main_column_name, main_column_value,join_column, depen_table, depen_column):
    if join_column!='NONE':
        check_query=f'''Select {join_column} from default.{main_table} 
                        where {main_column_name}={main_column_value}'''
        check_df=spark.sql(check_query)
        join_query=f'Select {depen_column} from default.{depen_table}'
        join_df=spark.sql(join_query)
        check_df.join(join_df,check_df[join_column]==join_df[depen_column],'leftanti')
        if check_df.count()>0:
            return 'Value has no value within dependancy table'
```

I have another function that I invoke to get a df with all errors (I shortened it as there are things not needed in this case:

```
def dq_check(metadata_df):
    error_columns=#schema I need
    errors_df=spark.createDataFrame(data=[], schema=error_columns)
    for row in metadata_df.rdd.collect():
        #metadata values assigned to variables
        query=#this would give me data from table based on the each row from metadata
        data_df=spark.sql(query)
        data_df=data_df.withColumn('DataError',concat_ws(' / ',col('DataError'),
        type_check(col(daas_column),lit(data_type)), #one example of data check
        join_check(lit(main_table), lit(main_column), col(main_column), lit(join_column), lit(depen_table),lit(depen_column))
        ))
        errors_df.unionAll(data_df)
    return errors_df
```

So basically when I am going through metadata, I get first some data into `data_df`:

| main_column | join_column |
| --- | --- |
| Some value | Join Value |

If I can't find in another table matching values based on join_column, I need an error string returned